# html clickable layout area. best practice

Tags: html, cross-browser

I am bad in html layout but I have to produce it :) I want to make big button on a page that is implemented as complex html layout with children tags (maybe - a bad idea).
I can handle click event on boundary element with javascript but it requires javascript enabled.
I can wrap boundary element with "anchor" tag but is doesn't work in IE

Please, suggest me the best way to implement this.

```
<a href="...">        
        <table>
            <td>                                
                ...
            </td>
            <td>
                ...
                   <table> ... </table>
            </td>       
        </table>

    </a>
```

Comment: Why not use a `<a>` element and style it accordingly?

Comment: Maybe html/css folks can understand what you mean without it, but I think it'd be nice to have a sketch of what you want to achieve.  I'm curious about what you mean.

Comment: @Pekka - methinks he should only use an anchor `<a>` if there's going to be a hyperlink. Otherwise a JS `onclick` event with a `cursor:pointer;` CSS property would be best.

Comment: When I put html layout into "anchor" tag (divs, images, spans) it doesn't work properly in IE. One decorated anchor tag can't satisfy me :(

Comment: Yeah, maybe a code sample or something. You can style an <a> tag the same way you can style a <div> tag, it just depends on the markup that exists inside that determines if this an option or not.

Answer (score 1):

Put an image inside the anchor. The image can be a 1x1 transparent gif. Give it a size that is equal to everything you want to cover. Position the image to cover your table. Then the anchor will contain the whole invisible image as something clickable. This works because it's the same as having a big clickable image and browsers support that.

Answer (score 0):

How about placing all of your content, then using css to absolutely position a giant `<a>` tag on top of it? The anchor wouldn't need child element's, they would be siblings. The absolute positioning makes the whole area clickable. But make sure the `<a>` is on top of the z order.

Comment: Anchor tags are not block elements, so they won't "cover" anything.

Comment: I tried this advise, assigned  "display:inline-block" to anchor tag and made it the same size as area it covers, but once again IE places anchor tag differently compared to FireFox :(  I suppose if I'll spend some more time on it, I'll make layout crossbrowser but may be there are better approaches?

Answer (score 0):

How about some simple JavaScript?

```
<div style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="javascript:document.location.href='...'><table>...</table></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Matthew, but it requires enabled javascript. I have to do something like that right now but wonder if I can live without javascript